# Looping through an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, count

Just wondering if someone could explain this to me? I have a program that asks a user to input a sentence. The program then reads the user input into an array and changes all of the vowels to a $ sign. My question is how does the for loop work? When initialising char c = 0; does that not mean that the array element is an int? I can't understand how it functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char words[50];
char c;

printf("Enter any number of words: \n");
fgets(words, 50, stdin);

    for(c = 0; words[c] != '\n'; c++)
    {
            if(words[c] =='a'||words[c]=='e'||words[c]=='i'||words[c]=='o'||words[c]=='u')
            {
                words[c] = '$';
            }
    }
printf("%s", words);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c` and `words[c]` are completely different things.  And since you defined `c` to be a `char`, what do you think would happen to this code if the upper bound were, say, 500 instead of 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code treats `c` as an integer variable (in C, `char` is basically a very narrow integer). In my view it would be cleaner to declare it as `int` (perhaps `unsigned int`). However, given that `words` is at most 50 characters long, `char c` works fine.

As to the loop:

1. `c = 0` initializes `c` to zero.
2. `words[c] != '\n'` checks -- right at the start and also after each iteration -- whether the current character (`words[c]`) is a newline, and stops if it is.
3. `c++` increments `c` after each iteration.

Comment: So I should really declare a seperate int variable to run the loop? i.e. leave char c and also declare int i = 0; then replace c with i in my loop?

Comment: @adohertyd: Yes, this is what I would do. I would also drop `c` since it will no longer be needed (it is only being used as a loop counter).

Comment: Ok so I just changed c to an int and the loop works the same. Is this more 'correct'? I should always use an int variable, even for a char[]?

Comment: @adohertyd: both versions are correct, but I'd argue that using an `int` is better stylistically. Note that the type of the variable used to index into an array (such as `words`) has nothing to do with the type of the array's elements.

Comment: @adohertyd No it's not more correct. It just takes up 4 times the amount of space. In this situation it is probably better to use an int, but sometimes space requirements are tight. Let's say you were storing a list of 1 billion integers, and all of them were < 256. Storing them all as `int` would use up 4GB of memory, but storing them as `unsigned char` would take up 1GB. In general it's a trade off between readability and wasted memory.

Comment: I suppose that was my original question. The type of variable for the index has nothing to do with the type of array. Thanks for the help you explained it very clearly. Much appreciated. User1, fair point I understand what you're saying but if we're talking everyday context then int has to be a better option than char. I suppose malloc would be better again but that's for a different day!

Comment: @adohertyd Also if you want to know how I'd do it in my own code that's not being worked on by a team: I'd leave it as a char because I don't like wasted memory and since I'm used to it now I don't find it any less readable. But I'd rename the char to `i` for iterator. So it would be `char i;` instead of `char c;` and changed everywhere else as well to make it obvious that it is a loop iterator, because I only use the variable names `i, j, k, l` as loop iterators.

Comment: @user1 - that's a valid point for the type of the *array*, but not necessarily for the index variable.  We're not talking about the difference between 4 GB and 1 GB, we're talking about the difference between 4 bytes (or more, or less) and 1 byte.  Personally, I use `size_t` for my index variables, because it's guaranteed to be wide enough to index any size array that's representable on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

An array is like a building, you have several floors each one with a number.

In the floor 1 lives John.
In floor 2 lives Michael.

If you want to go to Jonh apartment you press 1 on the elevator. If you want to go to Michael's you press 2.

Thats the same with arrays. Every position in the array stores a value, in this case a letter.

Every position has a index associated. The first position is 0.

When you want to access a position of the array you use array[`position`] where `position` is the index in the array that you want to access.

The variable `c` holds the position to be acessed. When you do words[c] you're acctualy accessing the `c`nt position in the array and retrieving its value.

Supose the word is `cool`

`word[1]` results in `o`,
`word[0]` results in `c`

To determine the end of the word, a the caracter `\n` is set at the last position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, `char` and `int` are implicitly converted.

You can look at a `char` in this case as a smaller `int`. `sizeof(char) == 1`, so it's smaller  than an `int`, that's probably the reason it was used. Programatically, there's no difference in this case, unless the input string is very long, in which case the `char` will overflow before an `int` does.

Comment: So you're saying that char c = 0; is converted to an int because of it's context in the for loop?

Comment: Hmmm... actually they're not converted only there. A conversion can happen when using `operator []`. You can use any type as an iterator, there's no restriction on that. And you can convert a char to an int directly and vice-versa, so char c = 0 converts **an int to a char**.

Answer (score 0):

Number literals (such as `0` in your case) are compatible with variables of type `char`. In fact, even a character literal enclosed in single quotes (for example `'\n'`) is of type `int` but is implicitly converted to a `char` when assigned or compared to another `char`.

Number literals are interchangeable with character literals, as long as the former do not exceed the range of a character.

The following should result in a compiler warning:

```
char c = 257;
```

whereas this will not:

```
char c = 127;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is C is an integral type as is `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` (and many other types):

It is defined as the smallest addressable unit on the machine you are compiling on and will usually be 8 bits which means it can hold values -128 to 127. And an unsigned char can hold values 0 - 255.

It works as an iterator in the above since it will stop before `50` all the time and it can hold values up to 127. Whereas an int type can usually hold values up to 2,147,483,647, but takes up 4 times the space in the machine as an 8 bit char. An int is only guaranteed to be at least 16 bits in C which means values between −32,768 and 32,767 or `0 - 6,5535` for an unsigned int.

So your loop is just accessing elements in your array, one after the other like `words[0]` at the beginning to look at the first character, then `words[1]` to look at the next character. Since you use a char, which I'm assuming is 8 bits on your machine as that is very common. Your char will be enough to store the iterator for your loop until it gets above 127. If you read in more than 127 characters (instead of just 50) and used a char to iterate you would run into weird problems since the char can't hold 128 and will loop around to -128. Causing you to access `words[-128]` which would most likely result in a Segmentation Fault.